# Cannot Set title of Dialog Using Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Ok so basically i have custom **ListView** and **onClick** of the list item (button) i wanna open a dialog Box which should basically show another ListView. I can view both list just OK, but issue is that my Dialog List View isnt showing list in a Dialog. Its just a transparent List on top of previous List. But if try to set Dialog Title   `getDialog().setTitle("Apps List");` i get the error mentioned above which means i dont have a dialog at 1st place but why?.

```
public class ProfileDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
     .........
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            ArrayList<String> listItemTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
            listItemTitle.add("Hello");
            listItemTitle.add("Hello1");
            listItemTitle.add("Hello2");
            listItemTitle.add("Hello3");
            ArrayList<String> listItemType = new ArrayList<String>();
            listItemType.add("Hello");
            listItemType.add("Hello123");
            listItemType.add("1234");
            listItemType.add("Hello6666");
            ArrayList<Integer> listItemId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            listItemId.add(1);
            listItemId.add(2);
            listItemId.add(3);
            listItemId.add(4);
            ArrayList<Profile> ProfileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < listItemTitle.size(); i++) {
                Profile Profile = new Profile(listItemTitle.get(i), listItemType.get(i), listItemId.get(i));
                ProfileArrayList.add(Profile);

            }

            View   profileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_dialog, container, false);
            ListView   profileListView = (ListView) profileView.findViewById(R.id.lstvSelectedProfile);
            getDialog().setTitle("Apps List");
    //        ListView   profileListView = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_dialog, null);
            if(profileListView.getParent()!=null) {
                ((ViewGroup) profileListView.getParent()).removeView(profileListView);
            }
                SelectedProfileListAdapter adapter = new SelectedProfileListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ProfileArrayList);
                profileListView.setAdapter(adapter);


            return profileListView;
        }
```

And this is my Adapater that populated the 2nd List.

```
public class SelectedProfileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Profile> selectedProfileList;

    public SelectedProfileListAdapter(Context context, List<Profile> selectedProfileList) {
        layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.selectedProfileList = selectedProfileList;
//        this.context = context;
    }

...........
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ProfilesListAdapter.ViewHolder ProfileListViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            ProfileListViewHolder = new ProfilesListAdapter.ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_profiles_list, parent, false);
            ProfileListViewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ProfileListViewHolder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ProfileListViewHolder.imageButtonMore = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonMore);
            convertView.setTag(ProfileListViewHolder);
        } else {
            ProfileListViewHolder = (ProfilesListAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ProfileListViewHolder.textView3.setText(selectedProfileList.get(position).getTitle());
        ProfileListViewHolder.title.setText(selectedProfileList.get(position).getType());
        ProfileListViewHolder.imageButtonMore = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonMore);
        ProfileListViewHolder.imageButtonMore.setTag(selectedProfileList.get(position).getId());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that you have returned the incorrect view in DialogFragment onCreateView(). You retruned "profileListView" which is only the list. Try to change it to "profileView". Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `onCreateDialog()` method and add your title there...

```
  @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setTitle("Apps List");
    return dialog;
}
```

**EDIT**

in your res/styles.xml: add custom dialog style

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Now apply it using: in your parent fragment

```
ProfileDialog fragment = new ProfileDialog();
fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Comment: No effect. Its still the same

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, it kinda helped me , but issue is that my Dialog is not looking like a dialog, its loaded in a dialog but its background is transparent. So i am not sure, whats wrong here.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007  I have a similar use case but I am adding a TimePickerDialog within a DialogFragment's Dialog onCreateDialog():  TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false);
        dialog.setTitle("Select a Time");
        return dialog;
The setTitle() is not working.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix?